# How to read an .xls file from AWS S3 using spark in java? And unable to read sheetName

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I am trying to read a .xls file from AWS S3 but getting java.io.FileNotFoundException exception.

I tried below two approaches. One by giving the path in option() with key location and another by adding the same path in load() as well.

```
Dataset<Row> segmentConfigData = spark.read()
                .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                .option("sheetName", "sheet1")
                .option("header","true")
                .option("location","s3a://input/552SegmentConfig.xls")
                .option("useHeader", "true")
                .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("addColorColumns", "False")
                .load();

Dataset<Row> segmentConfigData = spark.read()
                .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                .option("sheetName", "sheet1")
                .option("header","true")
                .option("location","s3a://input/552SegmentConfig.xls")
                .option("useHeader", "true")
                .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("addColorColumns", "False")
                .load("s3a://input/552SegmentConfig.xls");
```

I get file not found an exception. Similarly, when I read .csv file I am able to read the file.

Edit- I have solved this issue. I was using an older version of "com.crealytics.spark.excel". I was able to ready once I ungraded the jar.

But now I am facing another issue. I am unable to read any other sheet other then the first sheet. Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. I was using an older version of "com.crealytics.spark.excel". I was able to ready once I ungraded the jar.

Further, I was just able to read the first sheet of (.xls) file. Below is the code snippet:

```
spark.read()
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("location",path)
    .option("sheetName", sheetName)
    .option("dataAddress", "'"+sheetName+"'!A1")
    .option("header","true")
    .option("useHeader", "true")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("addColorColumns", "False")
    .load(path);
```